# How do I remove graphics in AS3 by choosing another alternative in a combobox?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, combobox

**I need help to clear the previous graph I made by clicking on a alternative in my combobox, WHEN I click the other alternative in the combobox.**

The coding might seem long and unnecessary, but I don't seem to find an easier way to write it. 
This project is about making a bar graph with content about accidents from drunk driving and speeding. Therefore I'm using a combobox to choose to show either the speeding graph or drunk driving graph.

```
cmpVelg.addItem({label:"Promillekjøring"});
cmpVelg.addItem({label:"Ulovelig hastighet"});

cmpVelg.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, klikk);
function klikk(evt:Event):void
{
    if (cmpVelg.selectedItem.label == "Promillekjøring")
    {
        {
        var proen:Shape = new Shape();
        proen.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        proen.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        proen.graphics.drawRect(90,170,30,180);
        proen.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(proen);

        var proto:Shape = new Shape();
        proto.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        proto.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        proto.graphics.drawRect(160,270,30,80);
        proto.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(proto);

        var protre:Shape = new Shape();
        protre.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        protre.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        protre.graphics.drawRect(230,300,30,50);
        protre.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(protre);

        var profire:Shape = new Shape();
        profire.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        profire.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        profire.graphics.drawRect(300,320,30,30)
        profire.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(profire);

        var profem:Shape = new Shape();
        profem.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        profem.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        profem.graphics.drawRect(370,280,30,70)
        profem.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(profem);

        var proseks:Shape = new Shape();
        proseks.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        proseks.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        proseks.graphics.drawRect(440,280,30,70);
        proseks.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(proseks);
        }
    }
    if (cmpVelg.selectedItem.label == "Ulovelig hastighet")
    {
        {   
        var has1:Shape = new Shape();
        has1.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        has1.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        has1.graphics.drawRect(90,310,30,40);
        has1.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(has1);

        var has2:Shape = new Shape();
        has2.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        has2.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        has2.graphics.drawRect(160,270,30,80);
        has2.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(has2);

        var has3:Shape = new Shape();
        has3.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        has3.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        has3.graphics.drawRect(230,210,30,140);
        has3.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(has3);

        var has4:Shape = new Shape();
        has4.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        has4.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        has4.graphics.drawRect(300,210,30,140);
        has4.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(has4);

        var has5:Shape = new Shape();
        has5.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        has5.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        has5.graphics.drawRect(370,200,30,150);
        has5.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(has5);

        var has6:Shape = new Shape();
        has6.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
        has6.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        has6.graphics.drawRect(440,150,30,200);
        has6.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(has6);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create two graphs but do not `addChild()` them yet. Also you need to create the graphs just once, instead of making new shapes per click. Like this:

```
var promilleGraph:Sprite; // object wide variables! Important!
var uloveligGraph:Sprite;
function init(e:Event=null):void {
    // or into the constructor of your main
    promilleGraph=new Sprite(); // creating promille graph
    var proen:Shape = new Shape();
    proen.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    proen.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    proen.graphics.drawRect(90,170,30,180);
    proen.graphics.endFill();
    promilleGraph.addChild(proen);

    var proto:Shape = new Shape();
    proto.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    proto.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    proto.graphics.drawRect(160,270,30,80);
    proto.graphics.endFill();
    promilleGraph.addChild(proto);

    var protre:Shape = new Shape();
    protre.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    protre.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    protre.graphics.drawRect(230,300,30,50);
    protre.graphics.endFill();
    promilleGraph.addChild(protre);

    var profire:Shape = new Shape();
    profire.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    profire.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    profire.graphics.drawRect(300,320,30,30)
    profire.graphics.endFill();
    promilleGraph.addChild(profire);

    var profem:Shape = new Shape();
    profem.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    profem.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    profem.graphics.drawRect(370,280,30,70)
    profem.graphics.endFill();
    promilleGraph.addChild(profem);

    var proseks:Shape = new Shape();
    proseks.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    proseks.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    proseks.graphics.drawRect(440,280,30,70);
    proseks.graphics.endFill();
    promilleGraph.addChild(proseks);

    // creating speeding graph
    uloveligGraph=new Sprite();
    var has1:Shape = new Shape();
    has1.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    has1.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    has1.graphics.drawRect(90,310,30,40);
    has1.graphics.endFill();
    uloveligGraph.addChild(has1);

    var has2:Shape = new Shape();
    has2.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    has2.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    has2.graphics.drawRect(160,270,30,80);
    has2.graphics.endFill();
    uloveligGraph.addChild(has2);

    var has3:Shape = new Shape();
    has3.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    has3.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    has3.graphics.drawRect(230,210,30,140);
    has3.graphics.endFill();
    uloveligGraph.addChild(has3);

    var has4:Shape = new Shape();
    has4.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    has4.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    has4.graphics.drawRect(300,210,30,140);
    has4.graphics.endFill();
    uloveligGraph.addChild(has4);

    var has5:Shape = new Shape();
    has5.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    has5.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    has5.graphics.drawRect(370,200,30,150);
    has5.graphics.endFill();
    uloveligGraph.addChild(has5);

    var has6:Shape = new Shape();
    has6.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x660000,1);
    has6.graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
    has6.graphics.drawRect(440,150,30,200);
    has6.graphics.endFill();
    uloveligGraph.addChild(has6);
    // rest of code follows as before
}
```

And then, it'll be as simple as removing one graph and adding another.

```
function klikk(evt:Event):void
{
    if (cmpVelg.selectedItem.label == "Promillekjøring")
    {
        if (uloveligGraph.parent) uloveligGraph.parent.removeChild(uloveligGraph);
        this.addChild(promilleGraph);
    }
    if (cmpVelg.selectedItem.label == "Ulovelig hastighet")
    {
        if (promilleGraph.parent) promilleGraph.parent.removeChild(promilleGraph);
        this.addChild(uloveligGraph);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never remove the children you created, use `while (mySprite.numChildren > 0) mySprite.removeChildAt(0);` to get rid off all cildren in a `Sprite` (`numElements` and `removeElementAt` if it's a `SpriteVisualElement`).

You can easily make this more comfortable to use. Create a function to draw your shape, like this:

```
function drawShape(lineThickness:Number, lineColor:uint, lineAlpha:Number, fillColor:uint, fillAlpha:Number, x:Number, y:Number, w:Number, h:Number):Shape 
 {
   var sh:Shape = new Shape();
   sh.graphics.lineStyle(lineThickness,lineColor,lineAlpha);
   sh.graphics.beginFill(fillColor, fillAlpha);
   sh.graphics.drawRect(x,y,w,h);
   sh.graphics.endFill();
   return sh;
}
```

And then create the shape like this:

```
var proen:Shape = drawShape(2,0x660000,1,0x660000.90,170,30,180);
```

As Vesper already answered, you can store these shapes in global variables (use `const` if they will **not** change, that's faster).